# Как svg использовать в значении button, для отправки ajax запросов?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, svg

Есть форма, которая отправляет комментарии ajax методом:

```
<div style="text-align: center;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 15px;" class="d-inline-block">
   <a onclick="post_query('add', 'reviewe', 'message')" class="d-inline-block py-2 position-relative">
      <i style="margin-left: 10px" class="send-arrow" width="25" src="svg/right-arrow.svg" alt="arrow"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

post_query это функция которая вызывает ajax запросы, она уже проверенна, не обращайте на нее внимание, дело только в теге , нужно его поменять и все ниже прикрепил саму svg кнопку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: в какой тег поместить svg кнопку, чтобы она работала как button и отправляла ajax запрос?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где вообще svg? вы имеете ввиду i с классом?

Comment: Вместо i вставляете свой svg. onclick переносите в a.

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov забыл одну строку внести, посмотрите пожалуйста еще раз

Comment: @Anton Mironov src="svg/right-arrow.svg" это вы имеете ввиду вставить вместо тега i, это как, кнопка все равно же должна иметь тег какой то???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Псевдо кнопка из линка

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 400ms;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<a onclick="alert('Hi')" class="d-inline-block py-2 position-relative">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1542.52 483" width="100px"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#515b5e;}.cls-1,.cls-2{fill-rule:evenodd;}.cls-2{fill:#caf200;}</style></defs><title>vialan_2</title><g id="РЎР»РѕР№_2" data-name="РЎР»РѕР№ 2"><g id="РЎР»РѕР№_1_РєРѕРїРёСЏ_" data-name="РЎР»РѕР№ 1 (РєРѕРїРёСЏ)"><path class="cls-1" d="M18,92C53.79,250.65,120.6,380.07,175.82,386.69h7.45C226.48,378,290.09,258.56,337.19,92.31L207,138.18c51.71,71.06,75.75,136-28.17,209.86C77.4,276.17,85.7,211.92,153.32,138.67Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M437.09,386.87H343.34c49.5-92.9,50.41-216.39-.63-293.85H444.62C388.59,166.7,384.28,291.84,437.09,386.87Z"/><path class="cls-2" d="M1542.52,483c-423.22-74.31-784.86-17.43-795-16.23,234-591.63-609-400-747.52-377.12C405.52-28.61,590.72-22.88,1100.52,66c-285-5.81-300,132.76-262,341.87,275,24.06,620.57,2.67,697.32-22C1512.6,396,1516.18,477,1542.52,483Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M1434.84,336.06c23.45-66.43,7.49-192.34-49.77-242.28,11.69,0,102.09-1,113.78-1-63.47,88.23-42.1,216.78-4.58,293.65h-80.73c38.68-38.57-92.6-142.5-189.12-224.9-25.52,80.71-5.95,167.76,27.47,225.95H1173c51.92-141.71,7.84-222.54-29.39-293.64h102.72C1215.15,181.14,1329.4,200.69,1434.84,336.06Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M760.62,387.69C725.51,229,659.23,99.43,604,92.68h-7.45C553.32,101.27,489.26,220.6,441.5,386.78l130.35-45.62c-15.86-21.91-29-43.24-36.68-64.42,38.36-24.47,91.12-26.66,136.77-7.26-7.49,23.17-23.61,46.73-46.42,71.3ZM530.4,218.38c6.65-28.21,27.81-56.9,70.45-87,45.88,32.72,69.23,63.82,74.61,94.85C626.6,251,569,247.83,530.4,218.38Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M1165.86,388c-35.11-158.7-101.4-288.26-156.6-295l-7.45,0c-43.25,8.62-107.32,127.92-155.07,294.09l130.35-45.62c-15.85-21.91-29-43.24-36.68-64.39,38.32-24.51,91.12-26.66,136.77-7.26-7.49,23.17-23.61,46.73-46.42,71.26ZM935.64,218.73c6.65-28.25,27.85-56.9,70.45-87,45.92,32.68,69.23,63.75,74.65,94.82C1031.84,251.35,974.19,248.18,935.64,218.73Z"/></g></g></svg>
</a>
```

Comment: спасибо, почти оно! все работает, но ньюанс, показывает почему то белую стрелку, я сделал по вашему образцу, как сделать невидимой эту стрелку? я ее добавил скриншот в сам вопрос :(

Comment: в смысле курсор убрать ?

Comment: Semenov как всегда, сначала написал, потом подумал, я разобрался, вы полностью решили мой вопрос, спасибо!